# Is there a way to test if accessibility zoom is on?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to know if there is a line of code like `isAccessibilityZoomOn` to test if accessibility zoom is on.  In a game I am working on, if you use zoom, the game glitches and a timer continuously goes, even though it shouldn't unless a finger is on the screen.  I'm currently using the `ccTouchesBegan` method to start the timer, but if you have zoom on and use three fingers to tap the screen you can remove your fingers and the timer continues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Apple lets you access that kind of information.  That is a strange effect, possibly caused by the tap to zoom in?

Comment: Yes, I think the 3 finger tap is making the timer continue.  I tried to fix this by not having the timer not start with more than one finger, `if ([touchArray count]>1) {} else {[self schedule:@selector(start:)];}` but this did not fix the problem.